# I need to export a tree in Blender 2.91.2

Tags: export, .fbx

The tree leaves are made of an transparent icosphere, and in the icosphere is a particle system with leaves (no animation, just still leaves). The icosphere is made transparent by adjusting the surface settings to *Surface > Transparent BSDF* and in settings making the *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend*.

How my model looks in Blender,
[image]

When exported (you can see the icospheres basically)
[image]

Comment: I guess you will have to adjust the materials again after exporting.

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: Probably this: [Why are there no materials or textures on my exported model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57531/78972)